# how do you create secret links that work?

Tags: html

I want to have a secret area that you can only get to by clicking an invisable link but any time I find a way to turn visibility off the link no longer works.

```
<tr>
<td><a href="pages/page1.htm">to Page 1</a></td>
<td></td>
<td><a href="pages/page2.htm">to Page 2</a></td>
<td></td>
<td><a href="pages/resume.htm">to R&eacute;sum&#0233;</a></td>
<td></td>
<td><a href="pages/frames/framed.htm">to Framed Page</a></td>
<td><a href="secret room/secret_room.htm" style="visibility: hidden;">shh</a></td>
</tr>
```

the secret link I am working on is the last one can anyone give me some pointers?

Comment: Why dont you make it the same color as the background?

Answer (score 1):

Make the font color the same as the background and edit some CSS to make the onHover color the same.

Answer (score 0):

A quick way to do it is with a `transparent` color:

```
<a href="secret room/secret_room.htm" style="color: transparent;">shh</a>
```